# Is the corresponding $\mathbb{C}[t]$-module cyclic?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^3$ and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator associated to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

- Is the corresponding $\mathbb{C}[t]$-module cyclic? Explain.
- How many $2$-dimensional $T$-invariant subspaces does $T$ have?
  Describe them.

Since the matrix is a lower triangular matrix, the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. But I don't know how to do the rest. Can someone tell me what I am suppose to do in general? (I have a couple other problems that are similar to this one.)

Comment: How do you define the corresponding $C[t]$-module?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown I'm assuming you're working with the module where you define $t\cdot v = T(v)$. (I suspect that being able to describe the module would be a useful first step to solving either question)

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, since if $ v_1, v_2, v_3 $ are eigenvectors with eigenvalues $ 1, 2, 3 $ respectively of $ T $, then the vector $ v = v_1 + v_2 + v_3 $ generates the entire $ \mathbb C[x] $-module $ V $. (Just apply $ T $ and $ T^2 $ to $ v $ and check the resulting vectors are all linearly independent; recalling the Vandermonde determinant makes it easier.)
- Invariant subspaces of diagonalizable operators are direct sums of their eigenspaces.

Comment: Would $\mathbb{C}[t]$-module be cyclic if there was an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2?

Comment: How does the second statement answer the second question?